# Extension point for AuthenticationManager

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using Spring Security for simple log in:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebAuthenticationConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final UserDetailServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public WebAuthenticationConfig(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, UserDetailServiceImpl userDetailsService) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
           
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/register/*",
                        "/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    
    }


    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

As you can see i am using default AuthManager. Now the `UserDetailServiceImpl` is simple:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserDetailServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<UserEntity> dbUser = userRepository.findUserByEmail(email);
        if (!dbUser.isPresent()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user found with email " + email);
        }

        UserEntity user = dbUser.get();

        return UserDetailsImpl.build(user);
    }
}
```

And in my controller i use it such as:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void loginUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginUserRequest request, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getEmail(), request.getPassword()));
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
}
```

This works just fine, authentication manager calls `getUserByEmail` of `UserDetailServiceImpl`, finds user, and then authenticationManager compares passwords and returning auth object.

However, what if i want to do another operations during this process? What if i want to log IP address of the user being logged?

I can extract IP address from `HttpServletRequest` in controller, however where is extension point for `AuthenticationManager` where i actually could plug in this functionality?

I could extend `AbstractAuthenticationToken` to accept details about Token ( so in my case i would pass, besides email and password , IP address to authenticate).

And then i could implement my own `AuthenticationManager`so it would not require implementation of my `UserDetailService` and thus my `AuthenticationManager` could look like:

```
public class MyAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager{
    
    @Autowired
    private final UserRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException{
       MyAuthToken token = (MyAuthToken) authentication;

       UserEntity user = userRepository.findUserByEmail(token.getName);
       // check if user exists and if password matches
      
       userRepository.addIp(token.getIP());
    }
  
}
```

But then i would lose whole flow of authentication manager, which i am not sure if its good since it seems robust.

Is there any extension point that i could plug my functionality into?

Thanks for help

Comment: you can use `HttpSecurity#authenticationSuccessHandler` and `HttpSecurity#authenticationFailureHandler` and implement the `ServerAuthenticationFailureHandler` interface or the `ServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler` and insert logic accordingly

Comment: Your configuration makes no sense. If you want form login, _use_ `formLogin()`, and don't try to use `STATELESS` with session-based (inherently stateful) authentication. Don't copy-and-paste code snippets together, especially in security code.

Comment: could you elaborate please? I will be adding JWT totken to it so i am not sure if what you said will still hold

Comment: @Toerktumlare thanks i will take look into that!

Comment: @Johnyb what he is meaning is that, what you have implemented is a custom login endpoint, that takes a Json body in a POST. So you have inherently written custom security, which is bad practice. Spring already comes with something witch is called FormLogin, which is fully documented in the spring security reference manual, which will basically automatically set up a `/login` endpoint for you. `FormLogin` is a standard for how to post form data to the backend and create a session with a client.

Comment: Returning a token from a `FormLogin` is also sort of bad practice, since a token, does basically already what a session does, but only worse. I suggest you google for the spring security reference and read about what Form Login is. I also suggest you read up on what "session based login is" as in what a "session" actually is. Then i suggest to read https://redis.com/blog/json-web-tokens-jwt-are-dangerous-for-user-sessions/ and https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/08/17/why-jwts-suck-as-session-tokens and http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/

Comment: And here you should really read up on the steps during a form login https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-form

Comment: @Toerktumlare thanks, i will check the sources, however if returning token from FormLogin is bad, inst setting up own /login endpoint good while using JWT?

Comment: using a token as a session at all is not preferred, even though many do it.

Comment: @Toerktumlare yes, but if i just return sessionID, and validate the sessionID on server/ retrieve user info frm DB, then the implementing of own /login endpoint is allright, or did i misunderstand it?

Comment: @Toerktumlare actually, why the FOrmLogin exists? Even on the doc page JDB authtentication is mentioned as different way, e.g different from FormLogin, but u usualyl want  JDB authentication for login?